# Will my app rejected from the Apple App Store?

Tags: iphone

I have submitted an app to the apple store. in my app I am using `NSRegularExpression`, and in the deployment target I did not put ios 4.0 (I have put 3.2) will my app rejected ?

Comment: Consider following [the App Stores proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores) on Area 51.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF your app crashes often, it may get rejected. If you suspect that it will crash often as a result of your use of a newer API on an older version of iOS, I would suggest rejecting the binary and then adding the appropriate conditional code to handle your situation. It's worth not frustrating your users.

Answer (score 2):

I think that's not the question.
You should reject your app by yourself, because devices with iOS < 4.0 will crash and they will rate your app with 1 star. Bad ratings will people keep off buying / downloading your app.

Answer (score 1):

NSRegularExpression is not available on 3.2 so your app will be rejected , just revoke the build you submitted , and upload the version with the correct settings.